# Can you say "добрый день" as a goodbye?

Tags: словоупотребление, phrase

In English you can say "good day" as either a greeting or a goodbye. Can `добрый день` and its morning/evening variants be used in the same way, or only as a greeting?

Comment: It's *Добрый день*, and no, you cannot use it as a *Goodbye*.

Comment: I am not sure about other flavours but in British English, as far as I know, *Good day* is not used as a greeting; and when it's used as a *goodbye* it implies sarcasm bordering on contempt. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Добрый день` cannot be used as a goodbye, only as a greeting.

On the other hand, you can use `доброго/хорошего/приятного дня/вечера` which is basically "(I wish you a) good day".

Comment: I am not sure *хорошего дня* is not a very recent calque of the English *Have a good day*. It sounds to me exactly as such.

Comment: Could be, but it's pretty widespread nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a general goodbye phrase, say *«Всего хорошего!»*.
It probably would work in any situation.

*«Приятного вечера»* is sometimes used, but it actually means having a nice time; so I would not say it to a person in the middle of boring work.
*«Хорошего дня!»* is not very usual, but correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
Добрый день!
```

But, yes,

```
Доброго дня!
```

is perfectly ok. Genitiv here indicates, that you are it is a perting wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can say `доброй ночи` and this will be only as a goodbye (good night).